# Class encypter does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am getting the following error message on Laravel 5.2:

```
ReflectionException in Container.php line 734:
Class encrypter does not exist
```

What could be causing this issue?

### Edit:

The error occurs when I add the following code to app.php:

```
    'providers' => [
    // Other service providers...

    Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider::class,
],

'Socialite' => Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::class,
```

Comment: Well this is not enough information to give you hints. We would need to know when this happens ( which route, which controller etc. ) provide more code and a more detailed problem description.

Comment: have you set key in config/app.php ?!

Comment: I have updated the question.

Answer (score 5):

Generate key 
`php artisan key:generate`

Answer (score 1):

I just got this error after adding code to `config/app.php` and it was due to permissions of `bootstrap/cache` folder. I cheked my permissions and updated the files owner to the apache user and it solved the issue.

I ran:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /path/to/project_root
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/project_root
```

And it worked just fine.

Comment: It didn't help me to solve the issue, but anyways the second line should probably start with `chown`, not `chmod`.

Answer (score 0):

For me this issued appeared when running a test where the tested code calls the `encrypt` function. This was caused by the fact that i was extending from the default PHPUnit `TestCase` class. This does not load Service Providers, which are required for the encrypter to work. Changing the base class to `\Tests\TestCase` solved this problem for me.